# How to Clear all row range rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to know how to clear the contents of all lines that are being hidden through this code, specifically in the two IFS.

I tried to include this excerpt:

```
  ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});}
```

but it is only cleaning the contents of the selected cell itself

```
function remcausa() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell=sh.getActiveCell();
  var row=cell.getRow();
  if (row<47) {
  sh.hideRows(row + 0, 4);ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});}
  else { if(row>50) {sh.hideRows(row -1, 4)};
  ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});}
}
```

the expected result would be to clear the contents of all the lines being hidden.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
function remcausa() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell=sh.getActiveCell();
  var row=cell.getRow();
  if (row<47) {
    sh.hideRows(row, 4);
    sh.getRange(row,1,4,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  }else if(row>50) {
    sh.hideRows(row-1, 4);
    sh.getRange(row-1,1,4,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect @Cooper 
You're saving me.Since yesterday you've helped me three times.Thank you very much.Until yesterday I knew nothing of these scripts,with your help I was able to learn some things already.Then I'll look for a course to learn this.I have an advanced knowledge with worksheets,however I still do not know how to develop a zero point macro(only work with advanced formulas).If you have some tips for beginners(best way to get the knowledge,where to get,etc),I appreciate it.To close my project here,only 1 macro is missing,I'm trying to do it myself,it's good that we learned with error.

Comment: I've learned a lot by just volunteering here.  I've used JavaScript for a long and most of my learning came from reading.  I've searched from a lot of answers on SO before I ever asked my first question.